# Keras model.predict results

Tags: python, keras, prediction

I am trying to create a model to predict if the text is a work reference or work description:
[image]

code:

```
X = df.v2
Y = df.v1
le = LabelEncoder()
Y = le.fit_transform(Y)
Y = Y.reshape(-1,1)

X_train,X_test,Y_train,Y_test = train_test_split(X,Y,test_size=0.15)
max_words = 1000
max_len = 150
tok = Tokenizer(num_words=max_words)
tok.fit_on_texts(X_train)
sequences = tok.texts_to_sequences(X_train)
sequences_matrix = sequence.pad_sequences(sequences,maxlen=max_len)

def RNN():
    inputs = Input(name='inputs',shape=[max_len])
    layer = Embedding(max_words,50,input_length=max_len)(inputs)
    layer = LSTM(64)(layer)
    layer = Dense(256,name='FC1')(layer)
    layer = Activation('relu')(layer)
    layer = Dropout(0.5)(layer)
    layer = Dense(1,name='out_layer')(layer)
    layer = Activation('sigmoid')(layer)
    model = Model(inputs=inputs,outputs=layer)
    return model

model = RNN()
model.summary()
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',optimizer=RMSprop(),metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(sequences_matrix,Y_train,batch_size=128,epochs=10,
          validation_split=0.2,callbacks=[EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss',min_delta=0.0001)])

test_sequences = tok.texts_to_sequences(X_test)
test_sequences_matrix = sequence.pad_sequences(test_sequences,maxlen=max_len)

accr = model.evaluate(test_sequences_matrix,Y_test)

print('Test set\n  Loss: {:0.3f}\n  Accuracy: {:0.3f}'.format(accr[0],accr[1]))

sample_texts = ["this is sample input"]

txts = tok.texts_to_sequences(sample_texts)
txts = sequence.pad_sequences(txts, maxlen=max_len)
preds = model.predict(txts)

print(preds)
```

Results:
Loss: 0.049
Accuracy: 0.980

preds = 0.95173115

My question: how do I output the label instead of score? Can anyone point me in the right direction, please?

SOURCE: https://www.kaggle.com/kredy10/simple-lstm-for-text-classification

Comment: Just round it...

Comment: so does it mean 1 will be work and 0 will be reference?

Comment: If that is how you defined them in `Y_train`, yes. --- You can also try different thresholds, other than 0.5, and see if the accuracy (especially the validation) improves.

Comment: But you should seriously consider using a `class_weight` in fit, because your data is highly unbalanced, and a high accuracy means nothing in this case.

Comment: Changed data to something more balanced. If i round the results i get what i expect, however when I add extra label I will get accuracy ~-200k?

Comment: `(preds > 0.5).astype(np.int32)` will give the required result